# Crul api request in loop very slow

Tags: php, foreach, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft graph API and in postman, they're all called really quick.  I am taking an array and pushing into a new array but I do this all the time and it's not slow?  Anyone see what I"m doing to make this data processing so slow?  It takes like a good 10 seconds. I put in the ob flush and start thing when I was searching for this problem.  It doesn't do anything?  The data is from a SharePoint calendar.  I have the id's of the items and I'm looping through to get each event time.

```
public function get_events(array $count, $access_token)
    { ob_start();
         $events = array();
        $request_header_auth[] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token;

        foreach($count as $ic)
        {

        $url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/hiddenForSecurity/items/'.$ic.'/'.'fields/';

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_header_auth);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        //if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
        $parsed_response = json_decode($result, true);
        array_push($events, $parsed_response['EventDate']);
        ob_flush();
        curl_close($curl);


        }
        ob_end_flush();
      return $events;

    }
```

Comment: Also the array is only 26 elements so it's not the fact that it's a massave array

Comment: I think the problem is that you are `curl_init` and `curl_close` inside your loop. Can you query bulk data and filter it (even afterward)?

Comment: lemme see : 10 seconds, 26 https requests -> 380 ms per request.  Not bad sherlock, what do you expect with a sequential/sync approach ?  Also take into account @wp78de remark.

Comment: Ok so Maybe I don't work with api's enough?  This is normal to wait 10 seconds for a loop like this?  Then there must be a more efficent way as I'm sure many have this same problem right?  I'm trying mulitCrul right now and thought it was working but still seems low

Comment: The mulitcurl thing worked a bit.  It's still slow but faster

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff that you do in above code and stuff that's getting done outside of it. It would really help if you could replace this with a [mcve] to make it more concise. Also, please measure and provide actual values measurements for the various parts. Your interpretation that something is "slow" or "really quick" is only of secondary importance. That said, optimizing code usually implies the use of a profiler.

Comment: thanks @UlrichEckhardt I ended up using multiCurl which takes the loop and makes it much faster.  Yes I have not worked with api's a lot in my life. I assumed 10 seconds to loop through 26 array points would universally be considered slow but I guess not when you're making an api call each time.  And I can appreciate you wanting more data but I can't really give out my company data so this is as descriptive as I could have been.  It's a 27 element array that holds the times meetings should be scheduled